# Can I use the hypotenuse of the pythagorean theorem to compute the work?

Tags: thermodynamics

A friend of mine told me that she used the hypotenuse of the pythagorean theorem to compute the work in graph below and the to compute the coefficient of efficiecy in this thermodynamics triangle cycle. What do you tnink about? [image]

Comment: Please explain yourself further, currently I have no clue where you are talking about?

Comment: Me and a friend of mine we were discussing about the work done in this graphic. In my opinion the total work is given by the area of the triangle. For she used the hypotenuse of the pythagorean theorem to compute the work.

Comment: Is this regarding a thermodynamic cycle?

Comment: Yes. it´s regarding to thermodynamic cycle.

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra yes you can do it and more over it might be the only way in this situation to calculate the total work done

Answer (score 1):

The work would be area of triangle, which is no way related to the hypotenuse (other than $\small H^2=P_0^2+V_0^2$)$$W=\frac12P_0V_0$$
Heat is :
$$Q_{in:A-C}=(C_V+R/2)\left(3\frac{P_0V_0}{R}\right)+C_V\left(2\frac{P_0V_0}{R}\right)$$
Efficiency is :
$$\eta=\frac{W}{Q_1}=\frac{\frac12P_0V_0}{(C_V+R/2)\left(3\frac{P_0V_0}{nR}\right)+C_V\left(2\frac{P_0V_0}{R}\right)}=\frac12.\frac{R}{3C_V+3R/2+2C_V}$$
$$\eta=\frac{R}{10C_V+3R}=\frac{R}{5fR+3R}=\frac1{5f+3}$$
which for  a monoatomic,diatomic and polyatomic(linear/non-linear) are:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\text{Monoatomic}&1/18\\
\text{Diatomic}&1/28\\
\text{Polyatomic-Linear}&1/28\\
\text{Polyatomic-Non-Linear}&1/33\\
\end{array}$$